# Run-time error '6335' when run code paste

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Run-time error '6335' when run code paste, as below picture
[image]

> Run-time error '6335'

Anyone who knows how to solve this problem? Thank you very much

```
sub test
selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine, count:=2
selection.EndKey unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
selection.Cut
selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine
selection.Paste 
end sub
```

[image]

Comment: Can you paste the code in the question as well? Plus a screenshot of the selection?

Comment: Screenshot of the selection...

Comment: `https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29003014/Word-VBA-Run-time-error-'6335'-in-Office-2016.html `  I found the same problem on this site but it did not solve it

Comment: Have you tried to restart your PC and run the code again? This seems to be the accepted solution?

Comment: What kind of content are you trying to paste? Are you able to paste it as a user, or do you also get an error? To what kind of target are you pasting? In the middle of text? In a table? In a graphic? ...?

Comment: This site is offering a fix. This is NOT a recommendation of the advertised product (I didn't try it and have no opinion about it) but I liked the explanation of error 6335. http://www.registryquick.net/runtime/Fix-Runtime-error-6335-How-to-Fix-Runtime-error-6335-61891.html

Comment: @variatus Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this, it could be that you are missing some references:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Selection.Cut
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (16)
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, but I do not know which reference is missing

Comment: @K.R.pnx - if the code above works, then it is the Word reference.

Answer (score -1):

"the error '6335' the action was blocked by organisation policy." well i think the error appears maybe because some other application is trying to access the clipboard. 
You have to shut down all applications that access the clipboard before you run the MS Word macro.
i was trying to generate the pdf in word document when this error appeared. finally i closed a process named "beyond compare clipboard" after which the macro worked smoothly.